# Как в .htaccess с кучей правил добавить 301 redirect (с "без www" - на "www")

Tags: redirect, .htaccess

Попыталась добавить обычный редирект:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.site-name.ru/$1 [R=301,L]
```

отвечает - "На этой странице обнаружена циклическая переадресация" и дописывает к url     index.php?next=

```
ErrorDocument 404 /errors/
AddType image/x-icon .ico 
<Files ".htaccess">
deny from all
</Files>
<IfModule mod_dir.c>
DirectoryIndex index.html$ index.php
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index.html$ index.php
RewriteRule ^admin/$ admin/index.php?%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)$ index.php?next=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)/$ index.php?next=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?next=$1&catid=$2
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ index.php?next=$1&catid=$2
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?
next=$1&catid=$2&action=$3
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ index.php?
next=$1&catid=$2&action=$3
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$
 index.php?next=$1&catid=$2&action=$3&zuma=$4
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ 
index.php?next=$1&catid=$2&action=$3&zuma=$4
```

На всякий случай - творение не мое, чего автор хотел достичь я не знаю, видимо сложносочиненных ЧПУ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
после 
RewriteEngine On
написать:
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^твое_имя_хоста [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.твое_имя_хоста/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Спасибо, все работает !

Answer (score 1):

делаю так

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\..+$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```